# Is there a way to make the font size of a label dynamicly adjust to the text thats put in the label In PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I get the current location of a player through an API, and I want the label to adjust its font size based on the length of the text I want to put in the label.

e.g. the string "Bedwars 4v4v4v4" fits fine:

[image]

but the string "Beast vs. Hunters Insane" gets cut off:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(893, 492)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../technostalk icon.jpg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setAccessibleName("")
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(
        "QMainWindow{\n"
        "background-color: rgb(54, 57, 63);\n"
        "}"
        )
        MainWindow.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 131, 91))
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox{\n"
        "\n"
        "border: 1px solid rgb(32, 34, 37);\n"
        "color: rgb(249, 249, 255);\n"
        "margin-top: 0.5em;\n"
        "}\n"
        "\n"
        "QGroupBox::title {\n"
        "subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
        "left: 10px;\n"
        "padding: 0 3px 0 3px;\n"
        "}"
        )
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 171, 51))
        self.label.setStyleSheet(
                "QLabel{\n"
        "color: rgb(0, 255, 0);\n"
        "}"
        )
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 101, 16))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
        "}"
        )
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 221, 91))
        self.groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(
        "QGroupBox{\n"
        "\n"
        "border: 1px solid rgb(32, 34, 37);\n"
        "color: rgb(249, 249, 255);\n"
        "margin-top: 0.5em;\n"
        "}\n"
        "\n"
        "QGroupBox::title {\n"
        "subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
        "left: 10px;\n"
        "padding: 0 3px 0 3px;\n"
        "}"
        )
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 211, 51))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet(
        "QLabel{\n"
        "\n"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
        "\n"
        "}"
        )
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 181, 16))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet(
                "QLabel{\n"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
        "}"
        )
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

Comment: Are you really sure you want to change the font size? Because if the problem is that the label is not completely shown, as I believe it is, then your issue is that you are not using a [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). Changing the font size dynamically to adapt to a specific size is generally discouraged, as it's very slow, it could create recursion and, usually it's done for the wrong reasons.

Comment: The Label is not completely shown becuase of the group box, and I want the font size scale so that everything fits in the boundary of the label(or the group box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Premise. Adjusting the font size of a label to ensure that it fits the width of its container is usually not a good idea, most importantly because having different font sizes for the same widgets makes the whole interface incoherent. Don't underestimate this aspect, as it's very important for the user experience.

Also, as already suggested in the comments, using fixed geometries is usually a very bad idea. While I can understand the specific case of a game interface, this doesn't prevent to use layout managers for the container widgets. The main reason for this is that what you see on your computer (or even in Designer) is rarely what the users will actually see on their screens, and if the user resizes the window (possibly to maximize it or even resize to fit a smaller screen) you'll end up in an ugly or even not usable interface.
So, I strongly suggest you to use a layout manager for the whole interface, and use fixed geometries only for certain child widgets (only the labels, probably).

In any case, a possible solution is to use a custom class that inherits from QLabel and promote each label in designer to that custom class (more on this at the end of this post).

Here is a possible implementation of a custom class:

```
class CustomLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def adjustFont(self):
        if self.parent():
            # if the widget has a parent, get the available width by computing the
            # available rectangle between the parent rectangle and the widget
            # geometry (logical AND)
            rect = self.parent().rect() & self.geometry()
            width = rect.width()
        else:
            width = self.width()
        font = self.font()
        text = self.text()
        while True:
            # compute the text width with the current font size
            textWidth = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font).size(
                QtCore.Qt.TextSingleLine, text).width()
            # break if the width is enough to show the text or the font size is
            # sufficient to keep the text readable
            if textWidth <= width or font.pointSize() <= 6:
                break
            font.setPointSize(font.pointSize() - 1)
        self._font = font

    def setText(self, text):
        super().setText(text)
        self.adjustFont()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.adjustFont()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.text():
            qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            qp.setFont(self._font)
            qp.drawText(self.rect(), self.alignment(), self.text())
        else:
            super().paintEvent(event)
```

A promoted widget is a way to use custom subclasses that implement features of the inherited class for special features.

To promote a widget you have to right click on it, select "Promote to...", insert the class name in the "Promoted class name" field, the file that contains the class in the "Header file" field (as a python module, so if the class is in the file "mylabel.py", insert "mylabel"), click "Add" and then "Promote".
Once a new promoted widget class has been added, you can promote other widget of the same type by selecting that promoted class from the "Promote to" submenu in their context menu.

Finally, remember that you should **NEVER** modify the files generated by `pyuic` nor try to mimic their behavior (read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)), so promote the labels in designer, save the file and generate it again with `pyuic`, then create a new script containing the following code (in this case, the pyuic generated file is named `mainWindow_ui.py`):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainWindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class CustomLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
# ... as the above example

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.label.setText('Short text')
        self.label_3.setText('Very very very very very very very very very long text')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Tysm for the detailed answer! But one more Question. In the complete application, I use various while loops in different threads that get information about the player and put it in the window. How can I do that while using the way you proposed (Welp I’m german do you say that xD) for the window.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. I suppose you're already using `self.somelabel.setText()` to update the labels during the game, right? If that's so, there's nothing to be done, as I already implemented the `setText()` for the subclass, and it automatically computes the font size accordingly.

Comment: nvm I can put the class MainWindow in function and make the function  a thread. Thx for your help, I will try everything out when I have access to my Computer tomorrow. Thx for the help again :)

Comment: @MergenStudios you're welcome. Remember that if you find an answer useful, you should upvote it (the up arrow on the left of the answer), while if that answer has actually solved your issue, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark symbol.

Comment: ok I tried it and I get an error

In the file generated by pyuic5 I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AutoResizingLabel'

I named the file with the class CustomLabel AutoResizingLabel and I made sure its all in the same file, do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: Is the file in the same directory of your script? Have you named it `AutoResizingLabel` or `AutoResizingLabel.py`?

Comment: I put everything (the file with the custom class, the file generated by pyuic and my main file) all in one directory, and the name of the file with the CustomLabel class is named AutoResizingLabel.py

Comment: Can you put all those three files in a github gist or some other pastebin site?

Comment: https://github.com/MergenStudios/API-Viewer hope this works. 

I never used github befor ;-;

Comment: @MergenStudios I cannot see anything, I only get a page not found error (probably due to accesss permissions) . Use github's gist ( yours should be https://gist.github.com/MergenStudios/ ), it's easier and perfect for temporary code snippets

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MergenStudios/be78438980671c921a83190ab43b15df 

here you go :)

Comment: As explained in the question, you must type the header file as a python module, so if the class is in the file "AutoResizingLabel.py", insert "AutoResizingLabel".

Comment: Ok, because I typed in AutoResizingLabel.py in the Header file, that explains it.

Comment: I tryed it, and it worked just fine, but I have one last issue. How can I set the text of a label from another function. This should explain what I want to do:
https://gist.github.com/MergenStudios/065df96244322892ba7d1ca50e1dfb53

Comment: Did you see the gist Link? I don’t know if stack overflow gives Notifications or whatever they’re called if I reply to my own Comment

Comment: @MergenStudios Widgets should *never* be accessed (nor created) from threads outside the main Qt thread. If you want to access them, you'll need to use a QThread subclass and custom signals that are emitted whenever you need to interact with the ui, then connect those signals with the widget function you want. I cannot tell you more about this matter, as it's off topic; I'd suggest you to do some research about using QThread and do some tests on your own to understand how to work with them.

Comment: Btw, for future reference, ensure that you carefully follow what explained in the answers and comments, as I clearly explained what to write in the header file section. Also, you can use @username to reply.